# Modules needed to create the best WYSIWYG experience?

Tags: input-formats, wysiwyg

What do you use to give the end user (editor) the best WYSIWYG experience, considering the following requirements (besides basic input):

- Insert images/flash and align then left/center/right with optional caption, choice of sizes
- Easily upload files and add links to them
- Add custom css classes to content
- Add custom buttons that provide custom/special formatting
- Be truly WYSIWYG, i.e. using styles/typography that the end user will see

From a developer/maintainers point of view:

- Keep front-end theme styles in-sync with styles used in WYSIWYG editor

Thanks, Egil.

Comment: Markdown :) There is no such thing as a "good experience" with WYSIWYG. IMNSHO.

Comment: berkes: for most of the time I would agree with you, but with none technical editors, Markdown is not ideal.

Comment: I was kidding. Sortof. And though what you say may sound true, in practice WYSIWYG are so ugly, UX-unfriendly, poorly supported and poorly integrated that *especially* for none-technical editors they provide far more trouble then that they solve. But again: I was kidding; let's not make this a pro/con WYSIWYG thread >:)

Answer (score 1):

You will need the Drupal WYSIWYG module http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg and the TinyMCE Library here http://www.tinymce.com/

TinyMCE supports plugins and you can make that "best WYSIWYG experience" that you are looking for. You can hook it up with your theme CSS and apply styles to the text aeras and see them in the WYSIWYG. Also check the WYSIWYG plugins page http://drupal.org/node/1197256